# Add custom subtotal

Tags: powerbi, powerbi-desktop

Is there a way to add custom subtotal for one level of columns in matrix?

[image]

I know there is an option subtotal but it sill add subtotal for all fields rows but I need to display total for only one level.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scroll down a bit in that Subtotals section and you should see this toggle:

[image: Per row level toggle]

If you turn it on, you can set exactly which levels for subtotals to display.